# WP Autocomplete through Ajax over PHP for entry field

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, autocomplete

I'm trying to have my database connected with an entry field that I have on Forminator.
Basically, I would like to have this behaviour :

- user type three letters in entry field
- the javascript retrieves the entry typed and send it to the database through ajax/json
- if there is a match it is sent to the UI

I wrote a WP plugin :

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Estimao
 * Description: Estimation de la valeur d'un bien immobilier. Cette extension permet d'estimer la valeur d'un bien immobilier.
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: SK
 * Author URI: 
 */


// Fonction qui effectue la recherche dans la base de données
function recherche_donnees($requete, $table, $colonne) {
    global $wpdb;

    $resultats = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT $colonne
        FROM $table WHERE $colonne 
        LIKE %s 
        ORDER BY $colonne 
        DESC", $wpdb->esc_like($requete) . '%' )
    );
    
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($resultats as $resultat) {
        $aff[$count] = $resultat->NOM_COMMUNE;
        $count += 1;
    }
    
    // // On renvoie les résultats de la recherche
    // return $resultats;
    
    // On renvoie les résultats de la recherche en format JSON
    if ( $resultats ) {
        return json_encode($aff);
    } else {
        $error = new WP_Error( '001', 'Aucun résultat trouvé.', 'Veuillez recharger la page' );
        wp_send_json_error( $error );
    }
}

function ajouter_autocomplete() {
    // Vérifier si jQuery est déjà chargé
    if ( ! wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'enqueued' ) && ! wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'done' ) ) {
        // Si ce n'est pas le cas, charger la bibliothèque jQuery
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }
    // Charger jQuery UI Autocomplete
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-autocomplete' );

    // Passer admin-ajax.php au script personnalisé
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-recherche', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/script-recherche.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'script-recherche', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
    // }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajouter_autocomplete' );

// Fonction qui ajoute le code JavaScript pour la recherche de données
function recherche_donnees_script() {
    
?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            
            // On ajoute l'attribut "data-autocomplete" à tous les champs de saisie de texte
            $('input[name="text-1"]').attr('data-autocomplete', 'wp_estimao_dvf_communes:NOM_COMMUNE');
        
            // On initialise la recherche de données
            $('input[data-autocomplete]').each(function() {
                var champ = $(this);
                var table_colonne = champ.attr('data-autocomplete').split(':');
                var table = table_colonne[0];
                var colonne = table_colonne[1];
        
                champ.autocomplete({
                    source: function(requete,response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
                            type: 'GET',
                            data: {
                                action: 'recherche_donnees',
                                table: table,
                                colonne: colonne,
                                requete: requete.term
                            },
                            success: function(resultats) {
                                response(resultats);
                                // Si des résultats sont retournés, les ajouter à la liste déroulante
                                if (resultats) {
                                
                                } else {
                                    $('input[name="text-1"]').html('<option value="">Aucun résultat</option>');
                                }
                            },
                            error: function() {
                                console.log('Une erreur est survenue');
                                console.log(requete);
                                console.log(resultats);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    minLength: 3
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php
    
}

// On ajoute l'action pour la recherche de données
add_action('wp_ajax_recherche_donnees', 'recherche_donnees');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_recherche_donnees', 'recherche_donnees');

// On ajoute le code JavaScript pour la recherche de données
add_action('wp_head', 'recherche_donnees_script');
```

I get this error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: resultats is not defined
    at Object.error ((index):162:21)
    at c (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.1:2:28327)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.1:2:29072)
    at l (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.1:2:80070)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.1:2:82499)
```

I desperately need help please... The variable `$resultats` seems to work inside the function `recherche_donnees()` BUT the same function called over an ajax request doesn't give any result (ie the error)

I tried every variable possible inside the ajax request with no results. Always returns the "error".

**EDIT**
I tried the following code based on what was suggested :

```
success: function (data) {
                                alert(data);
                            },
                            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
                            }
```

This is the result :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lyhwp.png)

Still nothing, if someone wants to help me debugging it...

**EDIT #2**

I changed the code of the function `recherche_donnees_script()` to display what it returns.

[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxmiB.png)

It prints this : [HETTENSCHLAG","HETTANGE GRANDE" "HETOMESNIL"]

[Here are the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkePm.png)

Comment: Do you know how to use the Javascript debugger in your browser's devtools to step through your Javascript code line by line? It's **incredibly useful** as you crank out this kind of client-side code. Absolutely the time you spend learning how to use that debugger will pay off hundreds of times over. You'll save tons of time by zeroing in immediately on this kind of trouble.

Comment: Hi I did try to use the Javascript debugger in my browser (chrome). However, it goes to other functions. at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> etc and I don't get it. Im lost

Answer (score 0):

It's basically saying in the error message that "resultats" is not defined. You did not create any variable with this name in your script. You can use "data" instead like this:

```
success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    alert(data);
},
error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(errorThrown);
}
```

However, it's difficult to fix it without debugging.

Comment: Yeah I caught that the variable "resultats" is not defined. But the thing is that the execution of the script never passes by success. I tried your code, it shows the alert of the error path. Here are the results : http://groupekems.com/debugging.png

Comment: You caused an 500 error with your call, most likely in your php code. When I look in your code, you are calling in your js the php function with the parameters "table", "colonne" and "requete" (in this order), but your php function takes "requete", "table" and "colonne" (in this order). So your sql request will fail. PHP will NOT match the correct parameters to the correct variables based on its name. 
Quick tip for further debugging: Always return step by step to avoid errors like this. If you had just returned the result after the sql query you would have noticed that it fails.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. Look at the edit #2 on the post. And I tried it too.